# Materialize Navbar Dropdown Menu doens't work

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, materialize

for some reason the dropwdown that appears in this section does not work.
https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!
There are no errors in the console, it just does not work, I have researched and tried several solutions that I found github and codepen but nothing seems to solve it, could it be caused by the library version? what should I do? this is my code

```
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and the script after call jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
   
    <ul class="left ">
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**link**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```